# Train listening to notes coming out of my trumpet

Tags: sound, trumpet, frequency, tuner

I'm with an old trumpet that sold me in Si Bemol(Bb), I'm still learning, and my biggest difficulty in music is being able to be constant in the sounds that come out of me, to reproduce them when I want and not randomly, that is, my ear does not make a difference very well the notes, and with that I can not reproduce, so I decided to train my problem using an online tuner:

https://www.flutetunes.com/tuner/

The problem is that I do not know if training with him is according to my trumpet, and I may be training wrong, which would be bad. If not is  according, can recommend me one so that I can train to hear the sounds coming out of me.

Comment: Si bemol is what the French call Bb.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the way forward. You need to train your ears to listen to the notes properly. Get a cheap keyboard - which *will* be in tune, and listen to the different notes, and how they work with each other. It will take some time to get good, pure, in tune notes on your trumpet, but using an app or tuner is not the normal way to go.

Comment: but how do I check if they are correct? I can be making a sound and another coming out and hearing wrong.

Comment: I'm following your tip, using https://virtualpiano.net/, I was able to be constant in 3 notes with my voice, which I could not before, training listening to them and checking on https://www.flutetunes.com/tuner/ if I'm doing it right. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely MUST take some lessons.  You don't even know, right now, whether you are breathing correctly, setting your lips correctly, etc.  Without someone to observe and teach, you may end up generating the incorrect over-or under-tones.